# Typing derivations in a specific style

Tags: packages, logic

How do I type such a derivation, with boxes around assumption, and vertical lines that "continue" those boxes from the left?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? I defined an environment `prooftabular` which is a `tabular` with three left-aligned columns, and in which a new command `\proofitem` automatically increments a counter and displays the number. I also defined a command `\assumption` to write these assumptions in boxes with the vertical line below. It takes two arguments: the number of rows the vertical line should span (excluding the one with the box), and the content of the box assumed to be in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newlength{\rowdepth}
\setlength{\rowdepth}{3.5pt}
\newlength{\rowtotalheight}
\setlength{\rowtotalheight}{14pt}
\newcommand*{\vertrule}[1]{%
    \smash{\rule[\dimexpr-\rowdepth-#1\rowtotalheight]{.4pt}{#1\rowtotalheight}}%
}
\newcommand*{\assumption}[2]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\vertrule{#1}}\(\boxed{#2}\)%
}
\newcounter{prooftabenumi}
\renewcommand*{\theprooftabenumi}{(\arabic{prooftabenumi})}
\newcommand*{\proofitem}{%
    \refstepcounter{prooftabenumi}%
    \theprooftabenumi%
}
\newenvironment{prooftabular}{%
    \setcounter{prooftabenumi}{0}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\rule[-\rowdepth]{0pt}{\rowtotalheight}}lll}
}{%
    \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftabular}
    \proofitem\label{sort}
        & \(* : \square\) & (\emph{sort}) \\
        & \assumption{5}{A : *} & \\
    \proofitem\label{var}
        & \quad \(A : *\) & (\emph{var}) on \ref{sort} \\
    \proofitem\label{weak1}
        & \quad \(* : \square\) & (\emph{weak}) on \ref{sort} and \ref{sort} \\
        & \quad \assumption{1}{x : A} & \\
    \proofitem\label{weak2}
        & \qquad \(* : \square\) & (\emph{weak}) on \ref{weak1} and \ref{var} \\
    \proofitem
        & \quad \(A \to * : \square\) & (\emph{form}) on \ref{var} and \ref{weak2}
\end{prooftabular}
\end{document}
```

It seems to work well, but the layout would break if lines were too long and the indent does not adjust automatically below the assumptions (hence the `\quad`s). I suspect there's probably a package in which an environment like this is already coded, and probably in a better way, but I don't know any.

Comment: There is, as you guessed, a package where this is already coded. Latex for Logicians is the place to look for this kind of thing.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

`flagderiv` is designed to typeset proofs of this kind. Not being a computer scientist, I'm not familiar with the package or your syntax, so doubtless the following can be fine-tuned to good effect. For example, I doubt `\lbox` is a good semantic name, but I wasn't convinced the symbol was being used with its usual meaning in the logics I'm familiar with, so I hesitated to name it accordingly. (I would use this symbol either as a unary operator meaning necessary or as an end-of-proof indicator, but neither seems to fit here.) Moreover, `flagderiv` offers a good many options to configure the appearance of proofs, which would reward further exploration if these are the sorts of proofs you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flagderiv}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\limp}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\rightarrow}}}
\newcommand*{\lbox}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\square}}}
\NewDocumentCommand \jrule {m} {(\emph{#1})}
\NewDocumentCommand \jruleon {mm} {\jrule{#1} on \ref{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{flagderiv}
  \step{sort}{*:\lbox}{\jrule{sort}}
  \assume*{}{A:*}{}
    \step{var-a}{A:*}{\jruleon{var}{sort}}
    \step{weak-a}{*:\lbox}{\jruleon{weak}{sort} and \ref{sort}}
    \assume*{}{x:A}{}
      \step{weak-x}{*:\lbox}{\jruleon{weak}{weak-a} and \ref{var-a}}
    \done
    \step{conc}{A \limp *:\lbox}{\jruleon{form}{var-a} and \ref{weak-x}}
  \done
\end{flagderiv}

\end{document}
```

It also would probably make sense to create another `\jrule...` for cases where there are two referenced lines. This is left as an exercise for the reader, since what makes sense here is very much going to depend on not only the semantics but individual preference.

[image: flag proof]

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the [Tikz package](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package) would be helpful.

For the other mathematical notations, you may simply use available commands where applicable in your TeX editor. e.g. `$A \rightarrow * : $ \square` gives

[image] as in (5) in your question.

But take note of the packages (i.e. \usepackage{xxx}) that the symbol uses.

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question which is about how to create the proof structure. It asks for help putting boxes around assumptions and continuing the vertical lines down the lines of the proof. It's true that the question includes no code and that some symbols are required to typeset the proof's content, but this is clearly not what the question is asking.